# CMMotionActivityManager Activities Not Printing When Calling

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-motion

I made sure to add Motion to my plist. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Below is my code:

```
import SwiftUI 
import CoreMotion

struct Settings: View {

    @State var walk = ""
    @State var run = ""
    @State var unk = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        Text("Stationary: \(walk)")
        Text("Walking: \(run)")
            Text("Unknown: \(unk)")

            Button(action: {
                self.startTest()
            }) {
                Text("Start")
            }

        }
    }

    func startTest(){
        let motionActivityManager = CMMotionActivityManager()

        if CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() {
            motionActivityManager.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (motion) in

                self.walk = (motion?.stationary)! ? "True" : "False"
                self.run = (motion?.walking)! ? "True" : "False"
                self.unk = (motion?.unknown)! ? "True" : "False"
                print(self.walk)
                print(self.run)
                print(self.unk)
            }
        }
        print("NONE")
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMMotionActivityManager queryActivityStarting data not available outside closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987303/cmmotionactivitymanager-queryactivitystarting-data-not-available-outside-closure)

Comment: I've checked if it's the async problem but I don't think it is.

Comment: Your `CMMotionActivityManager` is a local variable in your `startTest` function, so it will be released as soon as that function returns. You need it to be a property of your view struct at least (if not in its own model object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case (to make this view work) the fix is to make manager as property

```
struct Settings: View {
    let motionActivityManager = CMMotionActivityManager()

    // ... other code

    func startTest(){
        if CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() {

    // ... other code
```

but in general you have to place `motionActivityManager` somewhere at application-wide level (probably wrap in custom manager class), because `startActivityUpdates(to:)` can have only one hander. So you need to set up handler once and process/transform into your application wide notifications/events by yourself.

Comment: This solved the issued. It needed it to be at Struct level